# Consider the vector space V, of all 2×2 matrices where each entry is a polynomial of degree 2 or less

Tags: linear-algebra

The question in the textbook is this:

Consider the vector space $V := M_{2×2}(P_2(\mathbb{R}))$ of $2×2$ matrices whose entries are polynomials of degree 2 or less. A typical element of V has the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 & b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2\\c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2 & d_0+d_1x+d_2x^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Give a basis and the dimension of V as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

---

Here's my work and thinking.

Consider three sets A,B,C defined like so

$$A = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

$$B = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}x & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & x\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\x & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & x\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

$$C = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}x^2 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & x^2\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\x^2 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & x^2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

The set D forms a basis of V, where,

$$D = A \cup B \cup C$$

Sets A,B,C have 4 elements each. Set D has 3*4 = 12 elements total. The dimension of V is 12.

---

I'm curious if I'm making a mistake somewhere and perhaps making the basis set way too large? Having dimension 12 seems way too big in my opinion. Is there a smaller basis with smaller dimension possible? Please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Edited to take out the "D" at the end

Comment: Are you sure $D=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$?

Comment: You have done it correctly. Notice that you're sort of putting a $3$ dimensional space inside of a $4$ dimensional space. Don't let the polynomials fool you either, they're just an index like any other. Notice that there are exactly 12 scalar coefficients in the original matrix. That's why this is a 12 dimensional space.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't mean to put the D at the end. I meant to write $D = A \cup B \cup C$